# ef core linq group by with zero values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm creating request for linechart which shows count of payments per month.

```
private IQueryable<ChartItem> GetByMonth(IQueryable<Payment> data)
    {
        return from payment in data
               group payment by
               new
               {
                   payment.CreateDate.Year,
                   payment.CreateDate.Month
               }
               into model
               orderby model.Key.Year, model.Key.Month 
               select new ChartItem
               {
                   X = $"{model.Key.Month}-{model.Key.Year}",
                   Y = model.Count()
               };
    }
```

Is it possible to add in response empty grouping values using `linq`? I  mean adding monthes where there were no payments.

Comment: Just left join with a list of months.

Comment: @PauloMorgado It works, but I have to switch my query to client evaluation explicitly  in order to perform join with list of monthes

Comment: No, you don't. You do only that part client-side. Or you have a table of months in the database.